# QProgressBar updated from a QThread causes application to stall

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have an application using QMainWindow that has a long load task, so I create a QProgressDialog and Worker QThread. The thread periodically updates the QProgressDialog via signals. If the user moves the mouse over the progress dialog, then over the main application, the entire GUI stalls (which includes Window's fancy progress bar animations). If I then move the move back over the QProgressDialog, the application continues. I use the blocking queued connection for the signals from the thread, so the thread also stops while the GUI is stalled. Without a blocking connection, the thread will continue, but the GUI stays stalled. In this sense, I am using stalled to mean no GUI updates, but not unresponsive to the host OS.

I have tried inheriting from QThread and moving the worker to a QThread and both give the same issue.

In the following example, I can demonstrate the issue using both methods. I am not sure if this is a Qt bug, or if I have a misunderstanding of how to use QThreads properly. Change the `WORKER_QTHREAD` definition to 1 or 0 to toggle between inheriting from QThread and moving to a thread.

Sometimes, it is hard to get the GUI to stall, other times it is easy. In my real application it happens very easily, and usually immediately upon mouse out of the progress dialog. I added a description to the example with helper instructions for recreating the problem while the app is running.

Currently using Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.19) and Qt 5 (5.14.2) on Windows 10. It should be Linux compatible, but untested, and I am not sure if this issue exists on Linux.

Classes.h:

```
#pragma once
#if _WIN32
    #include <Windows.h>
    inline void sleep1() { Sleep(1000); }
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    inline void sleep1() { usleep(1000000); }
#endif

#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QProgressDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

#define WORKER_QTHREAD 1

#if WORKER_QTHREAD
class Work : public QThread
#else
class Work : public QObject
#endif
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    /// @brief Constructor.
    /// @param pd - progress dialog to update
    explicit Work(QProgressDialog* pd = nullptr)
    {
        if (pd)
        {
            pd->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
            const Qt::ConnectionType conn = Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection;
            connect(this, &Work::progressRange, pd, &QProgressDialog::setRange,     conn);
            connect(this, &Work::progressText,  pd, &QProgressDialog::setLabelText, conn);
            connect(this, &Work::progressValue, pd, &QProgressDialog::setValue,     conn);
            connect(pd,   &QProgressDialog::canceled, this, &Work::cancel);
        }
    }

    virtual ~Work() {}
    void cancel() { m_canceled = true; }
    bool canceled() const { return m_canceled; }

    #if !WORKER_QTHREAD
    void start()
    {
        assert(!m_thread);
        m_thread = new QThread();
        moveToThread(m_thread);
        connect(m_thread, &QThread::finished, m_thread, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(m_thread, &QThread::started,  this,     &Work::main);
        m_thread->start();
    }
    #endif

signals:
    #if !WORKER_QTHREAD
    void finished();
    #endif

    void progressText(const QString& text);
    void progressRange(int32_t minimum, int32_t maximum);
    void progressValue(int32_t value);

protected:
    virtual void run() = 0;

private:
    #if !WORKER_QTHREAD
    void main()
    {
        run();
        emit finished();
        m_thread = nullptr;
    }
    QThread* m_thread { nullptr };
    #endif
    bool m_canceled { false };
};

class Test : public Work
{
public:
    explicit Test(QProgressDialog* pd) : Work(pd) {}
    void run()
    {
        const int maximum = 100;
        emit progressText("");
        emit progressRange(0, maximum);
        for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
        {
            if (canceled()) break;
            emit progressValue(i + 1);
            sleep1();
        }
    }
};

class Main : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    Main()
    {
        setFixedSize(800, 600);
        setToolTip("Main window");

        QCheckBox* cb =
            new QCheckBox("Move the mouse over this dialog\n"
                          "Then move the mouse over the parent window, this window\n"
                          "Try moving the mouse in circles around the dialog without going over the dialog\n"
                          "The progress bar will stop moving\n"
                          "The thread will also stop processing because of blocking queued connection\n"
                          "Moving back over the dialog corrects the issue");
        cb->setToolTip("Checkbox tooltip");
        setCentralWidget(cb);
    }
    void showEvent(QShowEvent*) override
    {
        QTimer::singleShot(100, this, &Main::onStartup);
    }
private:
    void onStartup()
    {
        QProgressDialog* pd = new QProgressDialog(this);
        Test* t = new Test(pd);
        connect(t, &Work::finished, pd, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(t, &Work::finished, t,  &QObject::deleteLater);
        t->start();
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Classes.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Main m;
    m.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I don't have qt anymore to be able to replicate your app. Maybe this reference might be able to help.
 
https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: I looked over that article, and my example (when not inheriting from QThread) seems to follow the suggestions almost exactly. Thanks for the reference though

Comment: You **must not** access ui elements from outside the main (gui) thread.

Comment: I am not. I am sending a signal from the thread to main thread, so the main thread updates the ui elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the code from `explicit Work(QProgressDialog* pd = nullptr)` to `Main::onStartup()`? Weird things tend to happen when calling virtual methods from (thread) constructors.
Even though I could not reproduce your progress issues, I was not able to call `cancel()` with your code which did work after my modification.

```
 explicit Work(QProgressDialog* pd = nullptr) {}
```

and

```
void onStartup()
{
    QProgressDialog* pd = new QProgressDialog(this);
    Test* t = new Test(pd);
    pd->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    const Qt::ConnectionType conn = Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection;
    connect(t, &Work::progressRange, pd, &QProgressDialog::setRange,     conn);
    connect(t, &Work::progressText,  pd, &QProgressDialog::setLabelText, conn);
    connect(t, &Work::progressValue, pd, &QProgressDialog::setValue,     conn);
    connect(pd,   &QProgressDialog::canceled, t, &Work::cancel);

    connect(t, &Work::finished, pd, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(t, &Work::finished, t,  &QObject::deleteLater);
    t->start();
}
```

Comment: In testing, I did notice that `cancel()` worked when inheriting from QThread, but not when moved to a QThread. I was going to potentially ask about that next if it persisted past this current issue. I will try moving that code as you suggested. I added it to Work as a convenience so the 4 different loaders I actually have didn't all have to connect the same signals, but I can make a helper for that if it fixes my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving that code to `onStartup` did not improve the situation.